# Laminasの対応PHPバージョンやサポート期限を教えてください

Tags: php, zend-framework

ZendFramework1系で作成されたWebシステムの移行を考えています。
ZendFrameworkは開発が終了しているようで
後継FrameworkとしてLaminasが開発されているようです。

Laminasへの移行を検討しているのですが公式サイトやGitHubを見ても
対応するPHPのバージョンやサポート期限などの記載が見つかりません。
これはどこを探せば見つかりますでしょうか。

また、ZendFrameworkから移行しやすいものなどご存じでしたらご教示頂きたいです。
PHPの開発経験が浅いため、常識や暗黙の了解などがあれば合わせて教えて頂けると助かります。

Comment: 対応する PHP バージョンについては README への明記を求める Issue が既にあるようです。 - [Supported PHP versions should be included in the readme file](https://github.com/laminas/documentation/issues/24)

Comment: ありがとうございます。IssueもOpenのままですし実現されてない状態なんですね。記載の内容もリンク切れで結局対象バージョンはわかりませんし…。あまり採用されていないフレームワークなのですかね…。